# how to discretize R data.frame cloumn in a given width?

Tags: r

Say, I have a data.frame() like this

```
>head(Acquisition)
  original_date first_payment_date LTV DTI FICO
1       01/2007            03/2007  56  37  734
2       02/2007            04/2007  80  11  762
3       12/2006            02/2007  80  28  656
4       12/2006            03/2007  70  50  700
```

I want to discretize the Acquisition$LTV and Acquisition$DTI by the step size 0.05 and Acquisition$FICO by the step size 10.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer just use cut function is okay.

```
dis.LTV=cut(Acquisition$LTV,(max(Acquisition$LTV)-min(Acquisition$LTV))/0.05)
```